# How can I add a font to WhatsApp, Telegram, or Signal?

Tags: unicode, fonts, telegram, whatsapp

As the image below shows, WhatsApp (Web) now supports all of the active scripts in the Unicode BMP - incredible!  I believe all of those fonts are in the app itself - it's not relying on system fonts at all.

The penultimate line shows a phrase in the Musa alphabet, which is encoded in the Unicode Private Use Area at E000-E1FF.  As you can see, some of the codepoints are tofu, while others have emoji.

My question: is there any clever way to teach WhatsApp to use an installed Musa font to display those codepoints?  Or Telegram?  Or Signal?

[image: WhatsApp Script Test]

Comment: Update: It seems that with Google's publication of the entire Noto font suite to both Android and Chrome, the apps have all switched to rely on it.  Great!                     But the Noto fonts only cover Unicode, not our codepoints in the PUA.   So codepoints in that range still show tofu in WhatsApp, mixed with some emojis.  In Telegram and Signal, they show what I believe are Taiwanese characters missing from unicode.                    So my idea is to identify the fonts that are supplying the glyphs for those emojis and Taiwanese characters, and replace them with a Musa font.

Comment: Can anyone help me find those fonts in the apps?  They might be separate font files, or compiled into the executable code.

Comment: Oh right – PUA is the private use area. Maybe edit the written-out term into your post. Before I realised what PUA is, your questiond didn't make any sense to me.